# c# - Dictionary<string, List<string>> to DataGrid

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview, datagrid

i have the following problem:

I have a populated dictionary of lists, each lift has a specified, known length, and contains only strings, an example element would be:

```
d1[key] = [ "Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0" ]
```

The datagrid will have predeclared columns that correspond to the key, and each of the 8 list elements, for a total of 9 columns.

I have written this to try and populate the DataGrid, is there a more efficient way, basicly writing every single line onto the datagrid. The Dictionary may have upwards of 1k keys though.

```
public static void DictionaryToDataGrid(Dictionary<string, List<string>> inputdict1)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> d1 = inputdict1;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> item in d1)
        {
            DatagridForm.grid.Rows.Add(item.Key, item.Value[0], item.Value[1], item.Value[2]);
        }
    }
```

Is there a quicker, more efficient way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I think the method you are using is very efficient.

Comment: Just skip copying your parameter to `d1` and use `inputdict1`directly.

Comment: Would be better suited for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2):

A shorter version would be:

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> item in inputdict1)
        DatagridForm.grid.Rows.Add(item.Key, item.Value[0], item.Value[1], item.Value[2]);
```

It is also a bit more efficient since you're not creating a new variable ***d1***, and referencing the contents of ***inputdict1*** to it (thanks apocalypse).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It just assigns reference to a new variable. Nothing is copied to `d1`.